# textAngular and angular literally stripping <html> and <head> tags?

Tags: angularjs, textangular

I am using textAngular and angular. In my app, the user can write html code and preview it. It previews correctly using iframe, but I noticed that angular strips the `<html>` and `<head>` tags before displaying it to the textAngular editor. How do I prevent angular from doing this?

Here is my code in plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/W1YjV9qO3kzeBQbdgSKf?p=preview

Notice that the contents of the editor(`$scope.orightml`) starts with `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" ....` but when I click on the toggle html button (the button with the `</>` icon), only `<div class="alert alert-success">Hello World</div>` is left. I want to show the entire contents. I don't want any of the tags removed. How to do that?

Sorry for my bad english.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300">
  <style>
    .ta-editor {
      min-height: 300px;
      height: auto;
      overflow: auto;
      font-family: inherit;
      font-size: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js'></script>

  <script src='http://textangular.com/dist/textAngular-rangy.min.js'></script>

  <script src='http://textangular.com/dist/textAngular-sanitize.min.js'></script>

  <script src='http://textangular.com/dist/textAngular.min.js'></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="textAngularTest" ng-controller="wysiwygeditor" class="container app">
    <h1>Editor</h1>
    <button ng-click="disabled = !disabled" unselectable>Disable text-angular Toggle</button>
    <div text-angular="text-angular" name="htmlcontent" ng-model="htmlcontent" ta-disabled='disabled'></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    angular.module("textAngularTest", ['textAngular']).controller('wysiwygeditor', function wysiwygeditor($scope) {
      $scope.orightml = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/></head><body><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Hello World</div></body></html>';
      $scope.htmlcontent = $scope.orightml;
      $scope.disabled = false;
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello, I added my sample code.